# JMeter : How to read particular row data in csv file based on a column value and pass value of that column to a sampler?

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to Jmeter and doing a POC to do a load test on a web application.

**What I am trying to do:**
I have a total of 4 user logins(surgeons). Each Login is associated with 'n' number of patients.
I've created 2 CSV files
 1. one with the user login and password for surgeons
 2. another CSV file that contains the PatientName, PatientID and the Surgeon associated with that Patient like below.

> PatientName,PatientId,loginName
>   Pa1,PID1,user1
>   Pa2,PID2,user1
>   Pa3,PID3,user1
>   Pa4,PID4,user1
>   Pa5,PID5,user2
>   Pa6,PID6,user2
>   Pa7,PID7,user3
>   Pa8,PID8,user4

**My Scenario:**

1. Login as User.
2. Navigate to Each Patient Dashboard as per their associations.
3. log out of the application.

**My Testplan**

Thread Group (4 users, Ramp up time as 1 sec, 1 loop)
-csv1(with username, password )
-Login Page and Navigate to the Main page
- RunTime Controller (To sustain the load of a set amount of time)
-- While Loop(to loop between the patient dashboard of the surgeon/user logged in)
---CSV2 (the data as shown above)
----Navigate to Dashboard
----Navigate to Main
-Log out of the Application

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to use the single thread group and run it concurrently for all the 4 users. In this process, once the user login, the user should only those patient data from the CSV which are associated.
**For Ex:**
When the Thread1 is running with User1 login, he should only able to loop through Pa1, Pa2, Pa3, Pa4 users 
When the thread2 is running with User2 login, user should only read the Pa5, Pa6 data.

Like this, each user login should only pick those users as per their associations mentioned above.
Is there any way, I can use this single CSV2 file and achieve this task? so that I don't have to create n number of the thread of n numbers of logins with n number CSV files each containing the data specific to the user login.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

> **0. Configuration elements**
>
> 1. Pre-Processors
> 2. Timers
> 3. Sampler
> 4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

Being a [Configuration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) CSV Data Set Config is initialized once and before anything else therefore you won't be able to use the current variable from 1st CSV Data Set Config in 2nd CSV Data Set Config.

The solution is using [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead, JMeter Functions are evaluated in the place where they appear in the Test Plan so you can use any hardcoded value or JMeter Variable or another function there.

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)

Comment: I tried using __CSVRead() function, however the limitation here is , still we can't just use the single csv file where I can club all the patient data together the way I showed in the example. For now, I worked out a workaround by creating individual CSV files for all the surgeons with the respective patient data and saved them using the login name and then creating User Paramaters and  using the CSVRead(${username}.csv so that the repective file will be loaded and the values will be picked baed on the user which  just logged in. But I still need some help on resolving the actual issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
1. CSV Data Set Config for Surgeon credentials (loginNameSurgeon & Password)
2. Login Request (take first surgeon credentials from CSV) 
3. While ${__jexl3("${loginNameSurgeon}" != "${loginName}")} 
    a. CSV Data Set Config for patient data w.r.t surgeons (PatientName,PatientId,loginName)
    b. If Controller - ${__jexl3("${loginName}" != "<EOF>")}  // to check if we have any more loginName left
    c. Dashboard request
    d. Debug Sampler // Just to validate if the variables are in place.
4. Logout request
```

Comment: Still, the login will still run through the entire 2nd csv file without stopping at the "Pa4,PID4,user1" user record.which means, the sampler will keep picking the PID5,PID6 even thought are are not related to User1.  
My requirement is , when a trasaction controller and while controller used together, I want user1 to iterate through the CSV from pa1 to pa4 and then come back to pa1 and start the loop again.